# Oracle how to convert Timestamp with any Timezone, to Date with database server Timezone

Tags: oracle, datetime, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a timestamp column, which contains data with different timezones. I need to select records which belongs to a given 'day' of database server timezone.

For example, if the data in `MY_TIMESTAMP` column is `19-MAR-19 00.37.56.030000000 EUROPE/PARIS`.
And on given date `19-MAR-19` (also represented as 2019078) where the database server is on `EUROPE/LONDON`. 
Is there any way so that if my database server is in `EUROPE/LONDON` timezone, then this record is ignored but if it is in `EUROPE/PARIS`, then the record is selected.

**Please note** that the given timestamp is first hour of the day and `EUROPE/PARIS` is ahead of `EUROPE/LONDON` by one hour

The query I tried, unfortunately ignores the timezone of timestamp.

`select * 
from MY_TABLE 
where 
to_number(to_char(CAST(MY_TIMESTAMP AS DATE), 'RRRRDDD')) between 2019078 AND 2019079`

There is below mentioned way to convert TIMESTAMP from know timezone to a date in required timezone but I cannot use this logic as the source timezone is not know.

`CAST((FROM_TZ(CAST(MY_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP),'EUROPE/PARIS') AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/LONDON') AS DATE)`'

Comment: Aside - The names of IANA time zone identifiers are usually proper cased, such as `Europe/London`, `Europe/Paris`, `America/New_York`, etc.  Though most implementations use case insensitive comparisons, it's probably still a good idea to use the canonical casing.

Comment: As a further aside, by default Oracle displays timestamps with time zones as shown in the question, which can of course be overridden by using `to_char()` with an explicit format mask or by setting `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`. Either way, to get `Europe/Paris` instead of `EUROPE/PARIS` you need to supply that format element as `Tzr` instead of `TZR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert the table data; as well as being more work, doing so would stop any index on that column being used.

Oracle will honour time zones when comparing values, so compare the original table data with the specific day - and convert that to a timestamp with time zone:

```
select * 
from MY_TABLE 
where MY_TIMESTAMP >= timestamp '2019-03-19 00:00:00 Europe/London'
and   MY_TIMESTAMP <  timestamp '2019-03-20 00:00:00 Europe/London'
```

or if you want to base it on today rather than a fixed date:

```
where MY_TIMESTAMP >= from_tz(cast(trunc(sysdate) as timestamp), 'Europe/London')
and   MY_TIMESTAMP <  from_tz(cast(trunc(sysdate) + 1 as timestamp), 'Europe/London')
```

or if you're being passed the dates as YYYYDDD values (replace fixed value with numeric argument name):

```
where MY_TIMESTAMP >= from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(2019078), 'RRRRDDD'), 'Europe/London')
and   MY_TIMESTAMP <  from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(2019079), 'RRRRDDD'), 'Europe/London')
```

Quick demo with some sample data in a CTE, in two zones for simplicity:

```
with my_table (id, my_timestamp) as (
  select 1, timestamp '2019-03-19 00:37:56.030000000 Europe/Paris' from dual
  union all
  select 2, timestamp '2019-03-19 00:37:56.030000000 Europe/London' from dual
  union all
  select 3, timestamp '2019-03-19 01:00:00.000000000 Europe/Paris' from dual
  union all
  select 4, timestamp '2019-03-20 00:37:56.030000000 Europe/Paris' from dual
  union all
  select 5, timestamp '2019-03-20 00:37:56.030000000 Europe/London' from dual
)

select * 
from MY_TABLE 
where MY_TIMESTAMP >= timestamp '2019-03-19 00:00:00 Europe/London'
and   MY_TIMESTAMP <  timestamp '2019-03-20 00:00:00 Europe/London'
/

        ID MY_TIMESTAMP                                      
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         2 2019-03-19 00:37:56.030000000 EUROPE/LONDON       
         3 2019-03-19 01:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS        
         4 2019-03-20 00:37:56.030000000 EUROPE/PARIS
```

The first sample row is excluded because 00:37 in Paris is still the previous day in London. The second and third are included because they are both in the early hours of that day - the third row just scrapes in. The fourth row is included for the same reason the first was excluded - 00:37 tomorrow is still today from London. And the fifth is excluded because it's after midnight in London.

Comment: thanks for super quick and useful answer. 
Actually, I am working on big PROCEDURE where input is numeric date like 2019078, 2019079 etc. 

In order to convert it to a timestamp is there better way than below, so that same code works as expected in Paris and London.

`FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(2019078), 'RRRRDDD') AS TIMESTAMP), 'CET') AT TIME ZONE 'CET'`

Comment: You're doing more steps than you need: `to_timestamp(to_char(2019078), 'RRRRDDD') at time zone 'Europe/London'`. (Or whatever time zone region you actually want...)

Comment: Note, when you run `to_timestamp(to_char(2019078), 'RRRRDDD') at time zone 'Europe/London'` then Oracle does implicitly `FROM_TZ(to_timestamp(to_char(2019078), 'RRRRDDD'), SESSIONTIMEZONE) at time zone 'Europe/London'` - is that what you intent? Maybe `to_timestamp_tz(to_char(2019078)||' Europe/London', 'RRRRDDD TZR')` is less error prone.

Comment: Ah, I thought something didn't feel quite right with that, thanks. `FROM_TZ(to_timestamp(to_char(2019078), 'RRRRDDD'), 'Europe/London`)` would work too, right? I think that's more what I intended but got confused. (Your's is still simpler and maybe easier to understand...)